# Netty client stops reading socket data after days or hours

Tags: java, spring-boot, netty

I have the following scenario:

java 1.8

spring-boot-starter-parent 2.3.2.RELEASE

spring-webflux 5.2.8.RELEASE

spring-boot-starter-reactor-netty 2.3.2.RELEASE

The application runs on WebSphere Application Server 9

My application is a Netty client with reconnection support that reads the data that is sent to a socket. The data is taken and the start and end delimiters of the frame are searched, once it finds it, it sends it to the next handler which processes the information. After several days or only hours the client stops capturing the data that is sent to the socket, observing the log file the only error is:

`2020-08-13 15: 31: 34,885 ERROR [nioEventLoopGroup-2-1] i.n.u.ResourceLeakDetector [?:?] LEAK: ByteBuf.release () was not called before garbage collection`

This is main class

```
    public void run() {
        LOGGER.info("Levantando la aplicacion CAPTURADOR");
        closed = false;
        workerGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();
        bootstrap = new Bootstrap();
        bootstrap.group(workerGroup);
        bootstrap.channel(NioSocketChannel.class);
        bootstrap.handler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {
            @Override
            protected void initChannel(SocketChannel socketChannel) throws Exception {
                ChannelPipeline pipeline = socketChannel.pipeline();
                pipeline.addFirst(new ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter() {
                    @Override
                    public void channelInactive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
                        super.channelInactive(ctx);
                        ctx.channel().eventLoop().schedule(() -> doConnect(), 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                    }
                });
                socketChannel.pipeline().addLast(frameExtractor);
                socketChannel.pipeline().addLast(new LoggingHandler("SERVER_LOG", LogLevel.valueOf(logLevel)));
                socketChannel.pipeline().addLast(clientHandler);
            }
        });
        doConnect();
    }

    /**
     *
     */
    private void doConnect() {
        if (closed) {
            return;
        }
        ChannelFuture future = bootstrap.connect(new InetSocketAddress(remoteHost, remotePort));
        future.addListener(new ChannelFutureListener() {
            @Override
            public void operationComplete(ChannelFuture f) throws Exception {
                if (f.isSuccess()) {
                    LOGGER.info("Started Tcp Client: " + getServerInfo());
                } else {
                    LOGGER.error("Started Tcp Client Failed: " + getServerInfo());
                    f.channel().eventLoop().schedule(() -> doConnect(), 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

This is FrameExtractor class

```
    /**
     * En el método channelActive() que es al que nos llama netty cuando el canal de comunicación está activo,
     * aprovechamos para crear el buffer que mencionamos.
     */
    @Override
    public void channelRegistered(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
        buf = ctx.alloc().buffer();
    }

    /**
     * En el metodo channelInactive() que es al que nos llama netty cuando el canal de comunicación deja de estar
     * activo, aprovechamos para liberar el buffer que creamos @channelRegistered.
     */
    @Override
    public void channelUnregistered(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
        if (null != buf) {
            buf.release();
            buf = null;
        }

    }

 /**
     * Arma el envio de la medicion buscando el fin de trama y lo pasa al siguiente handler
     */
    @Override
    public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) throws Exception {
        try {
            Level level = ResourceLeakDetector.getLevel();
            // El msg que recibimos como parametro es un ByteBuf de Netty. Añadimos todo su contenido al final de
            // nuestro ByteBuf buf para ir acumulando el envio de bytes hasta que se encuentre el fin de envio de trama
            buf.writeBytes((ByteBuf) msg);

            String data = buf.toString(Charset.defaultCharset());

            int indexOf1 = indexOf(buf, Directlink.DELIMETER_DIRECTLINK, 1);
            int indexOf2 = indexOf(buf, Directlink.DELIMETER_DIRECTLINK, 2);

            while (-1 != indexOf2) {
                // Creamos un nuevo ByteBuf para copiar la trama hasta el indicador del fin de trama
                ByteBuf line = ctx.alloc().buffer();
                line = buf.copy(indexOf1, indexOf2 - indexOf1);
                // Agregamos al buffer buf todos los bytes hasta el indicador de fin de trama
                buf.readBytes(indexOf2);
                // Avisamos al siguiente handler, pasandole nuestro buffer line. No liberamos el buffer line porque es
                // responsabilidad del que lo recibe.
                ctx.fireChannelRead(line);
                buf.discardReadBytes();
                indexOf1 = indexOf(buf, Directlink.DELIMETER_DIRECTLINK, 1);
                indexOf2 = indexOf(buf, Directlink.DELIMETER_DIRECTLINK, 2);
            }
        } finally {
            // Liberamos el buffer que nos ha llegado por parametro. Como ya no lo necesitamos y no se lo hemos pasado a
            // nadie es nuestra responsabilidad liberarlo.
            ReferenceCountUtil.release(msg);
        }
    }
```

This is ClientHandler

```
    public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) throws Exception {
        ByteBuf buffer = ctx.alloc().buffer();
        try {
            buffer.writeBytes((ByteBuf) msg);
            byte[] bytes = new byte[buffer.readableBytes()];
            int readerIndex = buffer.readerIndex();
            buffer.getBytes(readerIndex, bytes);
            bytes = CapturadorUtils.eliminarParidad(bytes);
            String trama = new String(bytes);
            CapturadorGenerico capturadorGenerico = trama.contains(Directlink.KEY_DIRECTLINK)
                    ? capturadorFactory.getCapturador(Directlink.getDirectlink())
                            : capturadorFactory.getCapturador(Microcom.MICROCOM);
                    capturadorGenerico.parsearTrama(trama, bytes);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error("Error producido en el pipe ClientHandler con la trama: " + msg, e);
        } finally {
            // Liberamos el buffer que nos ha llegado por parametro. Como ya no lo necesitamos y no se lo hemos pasado a
            // nadie es nuestra responsabilidad liberarlo.
            ReferenceCountUtil.release(msg);
            ReferenceCountUtil.release(buffer);
        }
    }
```

Reviewing the code and analyzing the documentation https://netty.io/wiki/reference-counted-objects.html I did not find what the error could be. Buffers are released correctly.

Add the log file

```
2020-08-14 11:23:30,404 ERROR [nioEventLoopGroup-2-1] i.n.u.ResourceLeakDetector [?:?] LEAK: ByteBuf.release() was not called before it's garbage-collected. See http://netty.io/wiki/reference-counted-objects.html for more information.
Recent access records: 
Created at:
    io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBufAllocator.newDirectBuffer(PooledByteBufAllocator.java:349)
    io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBufAllocator.directBuffer(AbstractByteBufAllocator.java:187)
    io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBufAllocator.directBuffer(AbstractByteBufAllocator.java:173)
    io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBufAllocator.buffer(AbstractByteBufAllocator.java:107)
    cl.mop.dga.satelital.capturador.handler.FrameExtractor.channelRead(FrameExtractor.java:76)
    io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:374)
    io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:360)
    io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:352)
    io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1408)
    io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:374)
    io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:360)
    io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:930)
    io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:163)
    io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:682)
    io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:617)
    io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:534)
    io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:496)
    io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:906)
    io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:785)
```

Is in the lines

ByteBuf line = ctx.alloc().buffer();

line = buf.copy(indexOf1, indexOf2 - indexOf1);

I change the method

```
public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) throws Exception {
        try {
            // El msg que recibimos como parametro es un ByteBuf de Netty. Añadimos todo su contenido al final de
            // nuestro ByteBuf buf para ir acumulando el envio de bytes hasta que se encuentre el fin de envio de trama
            buf.writeBytes((ByteBuf) msg);

            String data = buf.toString(Charset.defaultCharset());
            LOGGER.info("Trama recibida: " + data);

            int indexOf1 = indexOf(buf, Directlink.DELIMETER_DIRECTLINK, 1);
            int indexOf2 = indexOf(buf, Directlink.DELIMETER_DIRECTLINK, 2);

            while (-1 != indexOf2) {
                // Creamos un nuevo ByteBuf para copiar la trama hasta el indicador del fin de trama
                ByteBuf line = buf.copy(indexOf1, indexOf2 - indexOf1);
                // Agregamos al buffer buf todos los bytes hasta el indicador de fin de trama
                buf.readBytes(indexOf2);
                // Avisamos al siguiente handler, pasandole nuestro buffer line. No liberamos el buffer line porque es
                // responsabilidad del que lo recibe.
                ctx.fireChannelRead(line);
                buf.discardReadBytes();
                indexOf1 = indexOf(buf, Directlink.DELIMETER_DIRECTLINK, 1);
                indexOf2 = indexOf(buf, Directlink.DELIMETER_DIRECTLINK, 2);
            }
        } finally {
            // Liberamos el buffer que nos ha llegado por parametro. Como ya no lo necesitamos y no se lo hemos pasado a
            // nadie es nuestra responsabilidad liberarlo.
            ReferenceCountUtil.release(msg);
        }
    }
```

And still have the error

```
2020-08-27 16:33:36,256 ERROR [nioEventLoopGroup-2-1] i.n.u.ResourceLeakDetector [?:?] LEAK: ByteBuf.release() was not called before it's garbage-collected
```

but now in line

```
buf.readBytes(indexOf2);
```

Add the class ClientWithNettyHandlers

```
`public class ClientWithNettyHandlers extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ClientWithNettyHandlers.class);

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("ClientHandler")
    ClientHandler clientHandler;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("FrameExtractor")
    FrameExtractor frameExtractor;

    private volatile EventLoopGroup workerGroup;
    private volatile Bootstrap bootstrap;
    private volatile boolean closed = false;
    private String remoteHost;
    private int remotePort;
    private String logLevel;

    @Bean
    public void run() {
        closed = false;
        workerGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();
        bootstrap = new Bootstrap();
        bootstrap.group(workerGroup);
        bootstrap.channel(NioSocketChannel.class);
        bootstrap.handler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {
            @Override
            protected void initChannel(SocketChannel socketChannel) throws Exception {
                ChannelPipeline pipeline = socketChannel.pipeline();
                pipeline.addFirst(new ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter() {
                    @Override
                    public void channelInactive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
                        super.channelInactive(ctx);
                        ctx.channel().eventLoop().schedule(() -> doConnect(), 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                    }
                });
                socketChannel.pipeline().addLast(frameExtractor);
                socketChannel.pipeline().addLast(new LoggingHandler("SERVER_LOG", LogLevel.valueOf(logLevel)));
                socketChannel.pipeline().addLast(clientHandler);
            }
        });
        doConnect();
    }

    /**
     *
     */
    private void doConnect() {
        if (closed) {
            return;
        }
        ChannelFuture future = bootstrap.connect(new InetSocketAddress(remoteHost, remotePort));
        future.addListener(new ChannelFutureListener() {
            @Override
            public void operationComplete(ChannelFuture f) throws Exception {
                if (f.isSuccess()) {
                    LOGGER.info("Started Tcp Client: " + getServerInfo());
                } else {
                    LOGGER.error("Started Tcp Client Failed: " + getServerInfo());
                    f.channel().eventLoop().schedule(() -> doConnect(), 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     *
     */
    @PreDestroy
    public void closeNettyClient() {
        close();
        System.out.println("Shutting down Netty Client: " + getServerInfo());
    }

    /**
     *
     */
    public void close() {
        closed = true;
        Future<?> future = workerGroup.shutdownGracefully();
        future.syncUninterruptibly();
        LOGGER.info("Stopped Tcp Client: " + getServerInfo());
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     */
    private String getServerInfo() {
        return String.format("RemoteHost=%s RemotePort=%d", remoteHost, remotePort);
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(ClientWithNettyHandlers.class);
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        InternalLoggerFactory.setDefaultFactory(Slf4JLoggerFactory.INSTANCE);
        SpringApplication.run(ClientWithNettyHandlers.class, args);
    }

}
```

Comment: Please enable advanced / paranoid leak detection as explained in the doc that you linked  and edit the question to include the logged stack trace.

Comment: Thanks Norman for the answer, it was the first thing I tried, I put the line ResourceLeakDetector.setLevel(Level.PARANOID) in the main class but the log did not change. Also I try to configure it from jvm -Dio.netty.leakDetectionLevel = PARANOID but I could not get it to show me a higher level of detail. I am using logback.

Comment: Anyone have any clues?

Answer (score 1):

The leak is cases by this:

```
             // Creamos un nuevo ByteBuf para copiar la trama hasta el indicador del fin de trama
            ByteBuf line = ctx.alloc().buffer();
            line = buf.copy(indexOf1, indexOf2 - indexOf1);
```

This will leak the buffer that you allocated via `ctx.alloc().buffer();` as you replace the `line` with calling `release()` before. You could for example fix this by using:

```
            ByteBuf line = buf.copy(indexOf1, indexOf2 - indexOf1);
```

Comment: Thanks Norman for the answer, now I test it and tell you if it worked

Comment: I made the change that Norman suggested but I still have the same error. 
Now in the line

buf.readBytes(indexOf2);

I do not release the buffer line because it is the responsibility of the next handler in the pipeline.
The buffer buf is where I store the information received and they are released in the finally.

Any clue?

Comment: You should update with how you changed it @MarianoGaston, to ensure that what you applied was the proper solution.

Comment: Read the java docs... readBytes(...) will return a new ByteBuf that you need to release once you are done with using. You most likely want to use skipBytes(...) in your use case

Comment: Hi Jason, when I did the tests I updated the post where it says "I change the method".
Thanks @NormanMaurer for the hint, I had not seen the method skipBytes(...). 
And as you say is more appropriate for the part where I detect the beginning and end of the frame, copy to the buffer line and I want to advance the readerIndex of the buf buffer. Now I test it and comment on the results

Comment: Thanks @NormanMaurer, after making the change I have had no more errors in the log. The problem is that the client keeps disconnecting after a while. Which may be?.
Any advice....

Comment: I update the question and add the ClientWithNettyHandlers class which is responsible for creating the Netty Client and defining the pipeline. It also has re-connection support using the doConnect method.
Perhaps you can point out any mistake that I am making in this class.

Comment: @NormanMaurer I forgot one piece of information, I have in my application a job managed by Quartz that runs every 5 minutes and execute another task. Iit may be that the use of Quartz crashes with Netty

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I solved the error by modifying the last handler in the pipeline and for each frame obtained I created a thread and sent it to continue with the application's own processing, parsing, insertion in the database, etc.
Perhaps Netty manages some prevention mechanism in the handling of buffers and by delaying the processing the buffer that was storing the frames until identifying the beginning and end of the same was full.
I want to highlight that the error that I had originally in the handling of the buffer could be solved with the advice of @NormanMaurer using skipBytes(...).